# Pd-GEM - using multiple, separate particle streams

Tags: puredata

I'm working on a live music visualisation project, where I am using a particle stream to visualise each channel of audio (vocals, guitar, percussion, bass) which are each coming from a looper.

I have the visualisation aspects working - I do envelope tracking in a separate pd instance, send the envelope details via udp to my gem instance, which then uses that to vary the size and colour of multiple particle streams.

The problem I have is that I am trying to set the origin point of each stream, and they are either interacting or they are controlling the origin of a *different* stream. The part_velocity also seems to be having a similar issue.

Each particle system has it's own gemhead (which I init as say [gemhead 20] so each one is unique), but changing the XYZ for its [part_source 1 point] object seems to affect a stream that's in a different gemhead chain.

I have also moved it off into an abstraction, where I name its head [gemhead $0] and I am having the same issue.

[This unanswered thread](https://forum.pdpatchrepo.info/topic/7560/multi-particles-system) from years ago shows two other people having the same problem, but no answers.

Here's a portion of my main patch which calls the abstraction:

[image: Main patch, shows call to abstraction]

And this is the abstraction:

[image: complete flow of ajg-particle-stream.pd abstraction]

Am I missing something simple here, or is there perhaps a bug in that one of the part_xxx objects is not checking which gemhead list it's in? Note that there are other gemheads in the main patch, some have an argument, some don't, but they're doing other stuff.

Oh yeah, and input is welcome on the somewhat dumb-looking way that I'm preserving state here, I've NO idea what the patterns are here, and cannot for the life of me find any good advice on it!

Comment: please post a minimal reproducible example that exhibits the problem (rather than screenshots of parts of your program)